Accessing Data through web saved on microcontroller SD card
I'm using a microcontroller (Arduino Uno) to collect sensor data and saving it in .txt format to the interfaced SD card. I would like to access this data remotely through web (WAN).
Please advise on how to do this and what kind of setup will be needed? Please share links of similar projects or relevant libraries.
Is it easier to implement it on any controller (ESP32 / Raspberry Pi)?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Arduino isn't a microcontroller. Arduino supports many microcontrollers. Perhaps this question would be better asked on Arduino.SE?

Since the question mentions I would like to access this data remotely through web (WAN), do you have an security requirements to meet? E.g. to mitigate against IoT security risks?

For now I'm not much concerned with security issues.

The simplest solution is probably something like a Raspberry Pi with a network connection and a customised web server, simply because of having a platform with an OS and also the large user base. The OP might consider posting on the rPi forum to get suggestions there.

There’s zillions of examples for esp32. https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp32-web-server-microsd-card/     It was the first hit. What was your search text? Mine was esp32 web server sdcard

There’s also the Tasmota project which is a full framework for IoT. I have a WiFi lightbulb running Tasmota with a VIC20 emulation I wrote. The VIC20 basic can talk to the lightbulb programmatically. I didn’t need a sdcard as the onboard serial flash was more than enough for 1 emulated floppy disk.

While it is for TI microcontrollers and processors, there is Internet of Things - IoT partners which are described as:

IoT platform partners offer cloud-based IoT platforms to which IoT devices may be connected. For each partner, at least one recipe or software download is available that enables a developer to quick connect a TI development kit to the partner’s IoT platform and begin IoT application development. Click on the partner name to access recipes and downloads.

Where starting with a software example from one of those partners may speed you development. I haven't performed any IoT product development, so have no recommendation for a specific IoT partner.
Perhaps one of those partners provides support for connecting Arduino Uno or ESP32 / Raspberry Pi based systems.
Looking at a sample of IoT partners from that TI page:

There is mention of Security – enterprise/personal, TLS/SSL
There is a list of Cybersecurity advisory, in case you need to track and mitigate against published security issues.

